# ModuleNotFoundError when using local dependencies

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-source-repos

The repo works on my machine but not on gcloud.

Structure of repo (on Google Cloud Source Repo):

```
project/
├── localdep.py
└── mylocalpackage/
    └── main.py
```

In main.py:

```
import localdep
```

Yet I receive the following error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'localdep'`

What am I doing wrong?! There is no problem running this on Pycharm on my machine, yet when I push to gcloud there is...

Comment: I'm not a Python expert by any means but I had a quick study at [The import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html).  It would appear from the error that your `localdep` is being searched for but not found.  Could it be as simple as having localdep.py in the same folder/directory as main.py?

Comment: Yes it is possible to do this but in the future I will be adding more localpackages and I need to be able to have this organised into folders. I've also taken a look at the docs and subsequently tried `from ..localdep import *`

Comment: Have also tried `from ..package import localdep`. When I do this I get `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

Answer (score 1):

The proper structure should be to have the main.py at the top level and the other files on the nested folders. You can take a look into this, which talks about [Structuring Your Project](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/).

Just in addition, I have tried with both `from ..localdep import *` and `from ..package import localdep`, and other like `from ... import localdep`, but either I receive `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`, or `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`.

It worth to rethink your project structure.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I will read it now. But the thing is, I want to have multiple Gcloud Functions using this same `localdep`, and I think having them all in the same repo is the ideal way to do this. Do you think there is a better way?

Comment: If your code has dependencies on that `localdep`, everything will be up to how you structure your code in order to reuse as much code as possible, always keeping in mind your own business logic. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/repo) you can find the documentation about deploying from source control, just in case you have not taken a look.